how to download multiple image in a div element container as all-in-one image file keeping the same position as it is shown on the page?
I have the following code :
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="model.png" class="download-image" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <img src="image2.svg" class="download-image" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
    
</div>  

<button onclick="downloadImages()">Download</button>

what could be the js code if I want that download button to download all the images in the imageContainer keeping the position they are asigned to? So the image downloaded in only one as it is shown on the page
<script>
        function downloadImages() {
            console.log('Button clicked!');
            const container = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
            const images = container.querySelectorAll('.download-image');

         
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        
            canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
            canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;

            let imagesLoaded = 0;

         
            images.forEach(image => {
                image.onload = () => {
                    imagesLoaded++;

                  
                    if (imagesLoaded === images.length) {
                        images.forEach(img => {
                            const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                            ctx.drawImage(img, rect.left - container.offsetLeft, rect.top - container.offsetTop);
                        });

                       
                        const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                    
                        const dataUrlForDownload = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:image/octet-stream');

                     
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.download = 'images.png';
                        link.href = dataUrlForDownload;
                        link.click();
                    }
                };
            });
        }

       
        document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', downloadImages);
    </script> ```

